# Sanitizing user inputs in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, validation, django-rest-framework, django-views

Wondering how to go about sanitizing user inputs in django rest framework. I currently have a views and serializer file but I am unsure of how to implement the process within these two files. I am not looking to use forms if possible

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source code of Django REST Framework's `serializers.py`, there are three methods of interest (https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L424-L503):

- `run_validation`
- `run_validators`
- `to_internal_value`

Depending on what you want to achieve in "sanitation", you may want to override one or more of those methods in your serializers and add your sanitation logic there.

(I presume you are using Django REST Framework, since your question is tagged as such.)